# How can I use a covering indexed view in a supported manner?

Tags: sql-server-2005, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, database-performance

According to [Unsupported Customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928224.aspx):

> Adding tables, stored procedures, or views to the database is also not supported because of referential integrity or upgrade issues.

I have a process that returns the most recently due phone call for staff to dial. This is causing a problem because we are a call centre, with a couple million calls already and adding a few thousand a day.

I'd like to add an [indexed view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx) which provides a [covering index](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) for the few fields required from the base tables. This will be indexed by due date and other criteria we use. I've estimated this could reduce ~1000000 logical reads every time the next call is requested to less than 100.

I know that adding a plain index is supported, but adding a view is not. The reason given above are RI and upgrades. **Will RI be an issue?** I'm not changing any constraint on the data, just keeping track of what is there. **Will upgrades be an issue?** It's only an index, I could drop it for the duration of any upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

We have added custom views in the past. Upgrades (**as well as rollups**) will be a problem for adding any objects like stored procs, views, etc. We have dropped them during the patching to avoid issues. THis is obviously unsupported, but Microsoft support is known to support even unsupported changes.