# Very slow search of a simple entity relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We use CRM 4.0 at our institution and have no plans to upgrade presently as we've spend the last year and a half customising and extending the CRM to work with our processes.

A tiny part of model is a simply hierarchy, we have a group of learning rooms that has a one-to-many relationship with another entity that describes the courses available for that learning room.
Another entity has a list of all potential and enrolled students who have expressed an interest in whichever course.

That bit's all straightforward and works pretty well and is modelled into 3 custom entities.

Now, we've got an Admin application that reads the rooms and then wants to show the courses for that room, but only where there are enrolled students.

In SQL this is simplified to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.CourseName, r.OtherInformation
FROM Rooms r
  INNER JOIN Students S
    ON S.CourseId = r.CourseId
WHERE r.RoomId = @RoomId
```

And this indeed is very close to the eventual SQL that CRM generates.
We use a Crm QueryEntity, a Filter and a LinkEntity to represent this same structure.

The problem now is that the CRM normalizes the a customize entity into a Base Table which has the standard CRM entity data that all share, and then an ExtensionBase Table which has our customisations. To Give a flattened access to this, it creates a view that merges both tables.
This view is what is used by the Generated SQL.

Now the base tables have indices but the view doesn't.

The problem we have is that all we want to do is return Courses where the inner join is satisfied, it's enough to prove there are entries and CRM makes it SELECT DISTINCT, so we only get one item back for Room.
At first this worked perfectly well, but now we have thousands of queries, it takes well over 30 seconds and of course causes a timeout in anything but SMS.

I'm given to believe that we can create and alter indices on tables in CRM and that's not considered to be an unsupported modification; but what about Views ?
I know that if we alter an entity then its views are recreated, which would of course make us redo our indices when this happens.

Is there any way to hint to CRM4.0 that we want a specific index in place ?

Another source recommends that where you get problems like this, then it's best to bring data closer together, but this isn't something I'd feel comfortable in trying to engineer into our solution.

I had considered putting a new entity in that only has RoomId, CourseId and Enrolment Count in to it, but that smacks of being incredibly hacky too; After all, an index would resolve the need to duplicate this data and have some kind of trigger that updates the data after every student operation.

Lastly, whilst I know we're stuck on CRM4 at the moment, is this the kind of thing that we could expect to have resolved in CRM2011 ? It would certainly add more weight to the upgrading this 5 year old product argument.

Comment: Would FetchXML offer a different solution ? I realise a more efficient way to solve this as SQL would be grouping by and selecting where the count is > 0; but it looks like grouping and aggregation weren't added till CRM2011 ?

Comment: Just felt it was important to be clear; If you extend the timeout - the RetrieveMultiple works and does indeed return the right results; this is why I'm specifically concerned with the database rather than posting my C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since views are "dynamic" (conceptually, their contents are generated on-the-fly from the base tables every time they are used), they typically can't be indexed.  However, SQL Server does support something called an "indexed view".  You need to create a unique clustered index on the view, and the query analyzer should be able to use it to speed up your join.

Comment: Funnily enough, I have found a similar solution to what you suggest but perhaps not too. It turns out that if I add another unrelated column to the select statement, the query optimizer suddenly realises that it can use an index and the whole thing runs in under a second. Sure it's counter intuitive to select more data to simply throw it away, but then at least the query fulfils the columns of a defined index and works. Whilst this fixes the bug, it's not elegant and ultimately I feel is unsustainable so I'll keep this question open for now.

Comment: Did you create and update the statistics on your original view columns?  Try that, then drop your unrelated column and see if the optimizer works better.

Comment: It *looked* like there were appropriate statistics, but I know these things can be misleading; I'll check with the DBA tomorrow.

Comment: This wasn't the precise answer but I'll accept it as it's very close to the right tracks and I doubt it could be answered more closely without an understanding of our CRM installation

Answer (score 1):

[Someone asked a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892914/how-can-i-use-a-covering-indexed-view-in-a-supported-manner) and I see no conclusive answer. The cited concerns from Microsoft are Referential Integrity (a non-issue here) and Upgrade complications. You mention the unsupported option of adding the view and managing it over upgrades and entity changes. That is an option, as unsupported and hackish as it is, it should work.

FetchXml does have aggregation but the query execution plans still uses the views: here is the SQL generated from a simple select count from incident:

```
'select 
top 5000 COUNT(*) as "rowcount"
, MAX("__AggLimitExceededFlag__") as "__AggregateLimitExceeded__" from (select top 50001 case when ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (SELECT 1)) > 50000 then 1 else 0 end as "__AggLimitExceededFlag__" from Incident as "incident0"  ...
```

I dont see a supported solution for your problem.

If you are building an outside admin app and you are hosting CRM 4 on-premise you could go directly to the database for your query bypassing the CRM API. Not supported but would allow you to solve the problem.

Comment: I fear that this is ultimately what we might have to do; thanks for confirming what I worried at least!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add this as a potential answer although I don't believe its a sustainable or indeed valid long-term solution.

After analysing the indexes that CRM had defined automatically, I realised that selecting more information in my query would be enough to fulfil the column requirements of an Index and now the query runs in less then a second.